# OpenCL events ambiguity

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, gpu

Referring to [clGetEventProfilingInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetEventProfilingInfo.html) documentation, `cl_event` resulted from [clEnqueueNDRangeKernel](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html) could be:

1. CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED

> when the command identified by event **is enqueued** in a command-queue by
>   the host.

2. CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_SUBMIT

> when the command identified by event that has been enqueued **is
>   submitted** by the host to the device associated with the commandqueue.

3. CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START

> when the command identified by event **starts** execution on the device.

4. CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END

> when the command identified by event **has finished** execution on the
>   device.

---

Assume visualizing the whole kernel profiling:

```
COMMAND_QUEUED -> COMMAND_SUBMIT -> COMMAND_START -> COMMAND_END
```

& the corresponding timeline:

```
Queueing -> Submitting -> Executing
```

Where:

- Queueing = COMMAND_SUBMIT - COMMAND_QUEUED
- Submitting = COMMAND_START - COMMAND_SUBMIT
- Executing = COMMAND_END - COMMAND_START

**Questions:**
**Is** my previous equations true? if so, **What**'s the real difference between queueing and submitting?
In other words, if I want to divide the whole process into COMMUNICATION (offloading) time and COMPUTATION (executing) time, **What** will be their equations?

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation seems fairly true. QUEUED is when you called the OpenCL API (such as clEnqueueNDRangeKernel). SUBMIT is when the runtime gave the work to the device. START is when it started execution, END is when the execution finished. There are three states between these four times. The first state is idle on the host. The second state is idle on the device. The third state is executing on the device. If you wish to combine the first two into "communication" then add them together (or use COMMAND_START - COMMAND_QUEUED).

Comment: when running on CPU, QUEUED=0 however SUBMIT isn't! why?

Comment: Don't know why. Sounds like a bug in the implementation.

Comment: i doubt because numbers differ on gpu, submitting takes more time than queuing! what implementation, those readings are from actual execution profiling!

Comment: You said COMMAND_QUEUED so I thought you meant the value returned from asking for CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED was 0, which would be a bug in the implementation (runtime). If you mean instead that the values from CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED and CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_SUBMIT are the same, making your calculated value "Queueing" 0 then that's fine. It just means the runtime spent no time in that state and submitted when you called the API.

Comment: Queueing is 0 in CPU, since there is no queueing when you only have a single task in CPU. However, if you had previously running kernels, queueing will not be 0. GPUs are different, since they are asynchronous you will always get some queing time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Is my previous equations **true**?

Yes.

> If so, What's the real difference between queueing and submitting? In other words, if I want to divide the whole process into COMMUNICATION (offloading) time and COMPUTATION (executing) time, What will be their equations?

**Queueing:**

- Time spend waiting for other tasks to finish in order to start the current one. In other words waiting for CL_COMPLETE state of all the depending events, or having free resources in the current queued queue.
- Note: CPUs will have 0 queue time when queueing to an idle device, because they are synchronous. While GPUs will ALWAYS have some small queueing time anyway (due to the asynchronous behaviour). This is the reason to pipeline as much as possible to GPU devices.

**Submitting:**

- Time spent preparing the current task (compile LLVM, move buffers, preparing device Cores, etc), should be small, but not 0.

If you are looking for a formula only "Submitting" and "Executing" are valid for calculating the current task overhead. Ignore queueing since it does not depend on your task:

```
Active% = Executing/(Executing+Submitting)
Overhead% = Submitting/(Executing+Submitting)
```